# how to set date_info->granularity

Tags: datetime

Is there anywhere in the administrators area can I set $vars['view']->date_info->granularity ?

With the recent updates to Drupal 7.32 the date format of the calendar module heading has changed from [month][year] to [day],[month][day number],[year] which looks silly.

I assume granularity has changed from 'month' to 'day', but I can't find where to change it back.

Is this associated with the fixed bug number [355058](https://www.drupal.org/node/355058)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [quick workaround](https://www.drupal.org/node/2294973#comment-9016311) for the issue:

**STEP 1:** Edit `modules/date/date_views/theme/theme.inc` and go find line 165.

**Change these two lines:**

```
$format_with_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . 'format_with_year', 'l, F j, Y');
$format_without_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . 'format_without_year', 'l, F j');
```

To these two lines:

```
$format_with_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . '_format_with_year', 'l, F j, Y');
$format_without_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . '_format_without_year', 'l, F j');
```

**Note: the only difference is one underscore character added to each line.**

Upload the changed file back to your web server.

**STEP 2:** Go to `(YOUR_WEBSITE)/admin/config/regional/date-time/date-views` and click Save. If you get permissions errors, try clearing caches.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Also need to manually apply patch in
https://www.drupal.org/node/2313587
to enable permissions on
(YOUR_WEBSITE)/admin/config/regional/date-time/date-views